# Complex SELECT with columns containing arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to perform a query in a PostgreSQL database with 2 tables:

1. `channel`
2. `videos`

and I want to get all users and 1 video per user with max view counts. I need to find users by the following criteria:

- any user with `name` similar to `id`
- OR any users with `title` similar to `id`

I managed to do it using following code:

```
   SELECT ch.*,
   yv.id as video_id,
   yv.title as video_title,
   yv.view_count as video_view_count,
   yv.tags as video_tags,
   FROM channel as ch
   LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT channel_id, MAX(id) as video_id
       FROM videos
       GROUP BY channel_id
       ) as vo 
       ON ch.id = vo.channel_id
       INNER JOIN videos as yv
       ON vo.video_id = yv.id
       AND (
           ch.name ILIKE '%${id}%'
           OR yv.title ILIKE '%${id}%'
           )
       ORDER BY view_count DESC
       LIMIT ${req.params.count}
```

There is a `tags` column in `videos` table and it has an array of tags (strings). I want to add new criteria - any videos with tag in `tags` similar to `id`.
I tried to add code below, but it doesn't work:

```
         AND (
           ch.name ILIKE '%${id}%'
           OR yv.title ILIKE '%${id}%'
           OR '%${id}%' = ANY(yv.tags)'
           )
```

As far as I understand - joined table has only 1 video, that's why it's not working.
It can be done in following way:

```
   SELECT ch.*,
   yv.id as video_id,
   yv.title as video_title,
   yv.view_count as video_view_count,
   yv.tags as video_tags,
   FROM channel as ch
   LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT channel_id, MAX(id) as video_id
       FROM videos
       GROUP BY channel_id
   WHERE '%${id}%' = ANY(tags)
       ) as vo 
       ON ch.id = vo.channel_id
       INNER JOIN videos as yv
       ON vo.video_id = yv.id
       AND (
           ch.name ILIKE '%${id}%'
           OR yv.title ILIKE '%${id}%'
           )
       ORDER BY view_count DESC
       LIMIT ${req.params.count}
```

It's not working, because:

```
   WHERE '%${id}%' = ANY(tags)
```

and

```
   AND (
       ch.name ILIKE '%${id}%'
       OR yv.title ILIKE '%${id}%')
```

is not related.

And how can I do something like this?

```
  '%${id}%' ILIKE ANY(tags)
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and your version of Postgres would help. Also clarify "users". We have tables `channel` and `videos`, no users table. How could `videos.title` define a *user*?

Comment: Answer for your problem with `'%${id}%' ILIKE ANY(tags)` is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101060/4147191